# RijndaelManaged Key generation

Tags: .net, encryption, rijndaelmanaged, symmetric-key

I need to encrypt data and store it in a file and later be able to decrypt it back.
For this I am using RijndaelManaged class. Now I do not want to keep the key hardcoded in the code. After some googling I found [this](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Code.aspx?Source=EncryptionCS&Title=Symmetric%20Key%20Encryption&Lang=C%23) method -

Here the key is generated but then all other values like passphrase, salt and IV are hardcoded. I do not have the option of letting the user enter the password, so I will also have to hard-code these values. So is this really safe? Can't some hacker use tools to find these hardcoded values and figure out the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot store secrets hard coded in an application. Period. If the prize is worth it, the secret can be found.

Viable solutions are:

- Use DPAPI through [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) classes.
- ask the user for a password
- use hardware modules (like an user badge)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand. You say you don't have the option for haveing a user enter the password so what are you envisioning. If your computer was magic and you could describe what you want, what is it you want?